# Programmatically creating new tags in Unity

Tags: unity, c#

I'm writing a custom editor script to add tags programmatically.

I got the error of IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range from the lines below:

```
SerializedObject tagManager = new SerializedObject(AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetsAtPath("ProjectSettings/TagManager.asset")[0]);
SerializedProperty tagsProp = tagManager.FindProperty("tags");
```

These are my codes:

```
SerializedObject tagManager = new SerializedObject(AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetsAtPath("ProjectSettings/TagManager.asset")[0]);
SerializedProperty tagsProp = tagManager.FindProperty("tags");

// Adding a Tag
string s = "Instantiated";

// First check if it is not already present
bool found = false;

for (int i = 0; i < tagsProp.arraySize; i++)
{
    SerializedProperty t = tagsProp.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);
    if (t.stringValue.Equals(s)) { found = true; break; }
}

// if not found, add it
if (!found)
{
    tagsProp.InsertArrayElementAtIndex(0);
    SerializedProperty n = tagsProp.GetArrayElementAtIndex(0);
    n.stringValue = s;
}
```

**Latest Update:**
Error IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range is solved by resolving file location in my original script. I apologized for that.

**Fixed:**
Added a line in the script to update the properties

```
if (!found)
{
    tagsProp.InsertArrayElementAtIndex(0);
    SerializedProperty n = tagsProp.GetArrayElementAtIndex(0);
    n.stringValue = s;
    tagManager.ApplyModifiedPropertiesWithoutUndo();
}
```

Comment: Did you try adding a breakpoint and going through the function in debug mode? That might help you giving us more precisions about the `it does not seem to be working` part

Comment: Ah, there is your problem, it is not working.  You need to make it work.

Comment: @realUser404 there's no way to debug the code by using breakpoint as the script is inherited from editorwindows. 

The error that popped up is IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range. from the lines below:

SerializedObject tagManager = new SerializedObject(AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetsAtPath("ProjectSettings/TagManager.asset")[0]);
SerializedProperty tagsProp = tagManager.FindProperty("tags");

Comment: As pointed out by others, _"it's not working"_ will not get you any relevant help. Describe what you want (you just did, which is nice!) and describe what you get instead.

Comment: There is an _"edit"_ link just bellow the question tags, use it to improve your question. Putting code in comments does not help clarify the question :)

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt Thanks as I'm new, just signed up today

Comment: Sure, no problem :) When you get the time, make sure to visit the [help] to understand the ins and outs of the site :)

Comment: That exception would indicate that there are no assets at the given path. Maybe the TagManager has been moved to a different path or you typo'd it? Also I think using [`AssetDatabase.LoadMainAssetAtPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.LoadMainAssetAtPath.html) could be a better choice than `AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetsAtPath`

Comment: @UnholySheep thanks as I resolved my file location in my original script. I also added one line to update the properties. Thanks a lot

Comment: Related: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/167986/add-a-tag-in-unity-editor-in-code/167987#167987