# Add a tag in Unity editor in code

Tags: unity

How to add a tag in editor? I am working on automatic asset generation and I would like to use tags for certain objects.
[image: Tag]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a utility method that allows you to do just that. Just replace `PathUtility.PROJECT_SETTINGS_PATH_NAME` with `"ProjectSettings"` if you don't want to have a constant somewhere.

```
PathUtility.PROJECT_SETTINGS_PATH_NAME = "ProjectSettings";

#if UNITY_EDITOR
public static class TagUtility
{
    public static void AddTag(string tag)
    {
        SerializedObject serializedObject = new SerializedObject(
            AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<Object>(
                Path.Combine(PathUtility.PROJECT_SETTINGS_PATH_NAME, "TagManager.asset")
            )
        );
        serializedObject.Update(); // Get object current state into stream.

        SerializedProperty tags = serializedObject.FindProperty("tags");

        for (int i = 0; i < tags.arraySize; ++i)
            if (tags.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i).stringValue == tag)
                return;

        tags.InsertArrayElementAtIndex(tags.arraySize);
        tags.GetArrayElementAtIndex(tags.arraySize - 1).stringValue = tag;

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties(); // Apply changes from stream to object.
    }
}
#endif
```